# Sample from discrete distribution using weights in Eigen Vector

Tags: c++, random, eigen, multinomial

I have a set of weights in an `Eigen::VectorXd` and would like to draw samples from the range of indices using these values are probabilities. If `weights` is a `std::vector` I can do this:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
std::discrete_distribution<int> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());
int val = dist(rng);
```

What is the best way to do this when `weights` is an `Eigen::VectorXd`? Can it be done without copying the vector and without writing the sampler myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use pointers for `Eigen::VectorXd`

```
std::discrete_distribution<int> dist(weights.data(), weights.data()+weights.size());
```

Comment: This doesn't result in the data being copied right?

Comment: Which data? weights? No.